# Selenium prevent Chrome settings tab from opening

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

I am working on a scraping application in C# that uses Google Chrome Driver. I am wondering whether there is a way to prevent the Settings tab from opening whenever the script opens the Chrome.

At the moment it is having some effects on the scraper. Sometimes the scraper stops completely after visiting the first page. To get a successfully scrape I have to close the "Settings" tab really quick in the 2 browsers that open.

### Update

It opens; `chrome://settings/triggeredResetProfileSettings` with an alert box `Windows Defender wants to reset your settings.`

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I've never observed chromedriver opening settings tab when scarping or automating a web application. Do you mean "chrome://settings/"?

Comment: It opens; `chrome://settings/triggeredResetProfileSettings` with an alert box `Windows Defender wants to reset your settings.`

Answer (score 2):

Try this, you may need to delete a registry key, worked for the person from the link

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/_pTMBYdpwUE